# How to Set Equal Width or Equal Height in StackView?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have six labels here, every two labels are stack in a horizontal view, and all horizontal views are stack in a vertical view, as show below

[image: Labels layout detail]

[image: Labels layout detail visually]

Here is what I want: I'd like to set `Label1`'s width 30% of `Label2` regardless of each label's content

The outer stack view is set as Aligment:Fill, Distribution:Fill Equally

All inner stack view are set as Aligment:Fill, Distribution:Fill

I have set `Label1`'s hugging to 250, and `Label2`'s as default (so does the others).

And I am trying to set the width by Equal Widths in pic 2. But it is unselected

what should I do about this? Preferring doing all the work in the storyboard, but working around in code is ok too.

---

Solution: Just need to select both label to add the constraint, as Below
[Solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKRf1.png)

Answer (score 6):

IMO, Stack View wont allow to give some fix frame size of the views inside it, we can somewhat control it using available properties.
 Stack Views are meant for similar type content to be confined inside one view.

**Option:**

- Take your Labels inside one *View*(Content View).
- Set the width of *Right label* equal to the *Left Label*, set the multiplier to `0.30`.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Let me know if you need more help, I have mentioned only one constraint.

Comment: I put a empty View in `Inner1` StackView, but the equal width  constraint is still unselectable. Will you please describe in detail? Thanks

Comment: The dark view is an UIView, I meant we can't achieve that using UIStackView. :)

Comment: @Stanley To access the equal width constraint you need to have selected *both* labels (use Command-click). It makes sense because equality is a two argument operator. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Bista Thanks for your reply, but it seems I just need select both to set the constraint, It's working for `Label3` and `Label4`. I'll post my solution in the question

Comment: Great! I'll try that too!